# How do I open a .diff file on a mac?

Tags: diff, filemerge

I have a .diff file but I don't know how to open it. I trie using FileMerge but that doesn't give me an option to open a .diff file.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diffs are just plain text. You should be able to open it with *TextEdit* or any other text editor. If you want syntax highlighting probably many of the fancier editors could do that. I just used *Aquamacs Emacs* to load a diff file and it provided some highlighting.

And if you want to ‘apply’ the diff to a file, use the *patch* command, like in [SanHolo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648686/how-do-i-open-a-diff-file-on-a-mac/1648714#1648714)'s answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `patch` from the command line, like you would on a Linux box.

```
patch original_file.c diff_file.diff
```

*Edit:*
I'm assuming that with "open" you mean to apply the diff file to the original. If you just want to take a look at the file, see [Chris'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648686/how-do-i-open-a-diff-file-on-a-mac/1648720#1648720) answer.

Answer (score 3):

Vim offers coloration for diff files. If you'd rather go graphical, use [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) (which is free) or [TextMate](http://macromates.com) (not free).

**TextMate**
[image: TextMate]

**MacVim**
[image: MacVim]

**Vim**
[image: Vim]

Answer (score 1):

Kompare opens .diff in convenient view